# How are electronic configurations including hybrid orbitals notated?

Tags: electronic-configuration, hybridization

I know the general scheme for notating electronic configurations is (with s and p orbitals) [noble gas core]ns<sup>el.</sup>$n$p<sup>el.</sup> etc., where $n$ is the principal quantum number and el. is the number of electrons occupying that subshell, e.g. carbon: [He]2s<sup>2</sup>2p<sup>2</sup>.

Now, how do you include hybrid orbitals? The problem arises because some hybrid orbitals already have superscript numbers (sp<sup>2</sup>, sp<sup>3</sup> …) – how do you differentiate between these superscript numbers and those denoting how many electrons fill that orbital? If I were to write out the electronic configuration for the hybridised carbon atom in $\ce{CO2}$, this would not be a problem: [He]2sp<sup>2</sup>2p<sup>2</sup>, but what about the carbon atom in $\ce{CH4}$, which has sp<sup>3</sup> orbitals? Would you write [He]2sp<sup>3, 4</sup> or [He]2sp<sub>3</sub><sup>4</sup> or something else?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electronic configuration concept does not really extend itself well to hybrid orbitals, because these are best considered mathematical concepts only. However, the problem is easily solveable:

**Always use brackets when dealing with hybrid orbitals.**

Even your $\ce{CO2}$ case is potentially misleading: I misread it once as $\mathrm{2s^1\ 2p^2}$. It is best to show what belongs together with: $\mathrm{[He]\ 2(sp)^2\ 2p^2}$ or, for methane: $\mathrm{[He]\ 2(sp^3)^4}$.

Comment: What description of bonding is anything more  than a mathematical concept?

Comment: @ron True, but turn it around. The orbitals of an atom in ground state are about the closest we can get to quantumphysical reality. I didn’t want to stress that other descriptions of bonds be less mathematical but rather that the ground state is less so.